# What is float in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point

I wrote this code:

```
float b = 3.6;
```

and I get this:

```
Error:Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float
```

Why?  Whats the definition of `float`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Why do you need to specify an 'f' in a float literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102955/java-why-do-you-need-to-specify-an-f-in-a-float-literal)

Comment: @Sneftel That is not a duplicate of this question. This question asks why it doesn't compile (to which the answer is ' you must add a `f` to the literal'), while the other question asks why you must add the `f`. Although they are related, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217401/does-the-new-guidance-on-duplicate-questions-suggest-closing-a-question-as-dupli . The answers to the linked question are answers to this question.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

In Java, when you type a decimal number as `3.6`, its interpreted as a `double`. `double` is a 64-bit precision IEEE 754 floating point, while `float`is a 32-bit  precision IEEE 754 floating point. As a `float` is less precise than a `double`, the conversion cannot be performed implicitly.

If you want to create a float, you should end your number with `f` (i.e.: `3.6f`).

For more explanation, see the [primitive data types definition of the Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 49):

Make it

```
float b= 3.6f;
```

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d

- [Read More](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)

Comment: Is there a way to check if a string has only float value ?

Answer (score 13):

The thing is that decimal numbers defaults to double. And since double doesn't fit into float you have to tell explicitely you intentionally define a float. So go with:

```
float b = 3.6f;
```

Answer (score 9):

In JAVA, values like:

1. 8.5
2. 3.9
3. (and so on..)

Is assumed as **double** and not **float**.

You can also perform a cast in order to solve the problem:

`float b = (float) 3.5`;

Another solution:

`float b = 3.5f`;