# Unexpected decimal result

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal

I run the following code, but did not expect that result..

```
public class SampleDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        System.out.println(10.00 - 9.10);
    }
}
```

I am getting o/p as **0.9000000000000004**

Why is it so?

Comment: Read all those Related questions on the side there --->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076710/what-is-float-in-java

Comment: [Welcome to floating point arithmetic.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/62948/what-can-be-done-to-programming-languages-to-avoid-floating-point-pitfalls) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because decimal values can’t be represented exactly by float or double.

**One suggestion : Avoid float and double where exact answers are required. Use BigDecimal, int, or long instead**

---

**Using int :**

```
public class SampleDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        System.out.println(10 - 9);
    }
}

// Output : 1
```

**Using BigDecimal :**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class SampleDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println(new BigDecimal("10.00").subtract(new BigDecimal("9.10")));
                             }
                     }
// Output : 0.90
```

Comment: Just to point out, if you need this kind of precision, go for [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which gives you more control over precision, scale, rounding politics, etc.

Comment: Yes, @Anthony +1 I added it to my answer. :)