# Getting wrong result for evaluation of 100 * 2.55 values

Tags: java

I am getting wrong result using below method.

```
public double evaluate(final double leftOperand, final double rightOperand) {
        Double rtnValue = new Double(leftOperand * rightOperand);
        return rtnValue.doubleValue();
    }
```

Enter Parameter value are: leftOperand= 100 and rightOperand=2.55

I am getting Wrong answer:  **254.99999999999997**

The correct answer is a **255.0**

Comment: Obligatory "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"-link: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: What *exact* value do you believe your value of "2.55" has?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Even if you know the exact value of both 2.55 and 100.0, the answer would be wrong...

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: I don't believe that's the case. When both source operands and the target value are all exactly representable, I *believe* IEEE-754 guarantees that the result will be "correct".

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075422/unexpected-decimal-result?lq=1

Comment: @JonSkeet: I wrote a test case: http://ideone.com/1Sazg  What do you think? I think that it isn't correct, as I though. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: You're still using 2.55d, which *isn't* exactly 2.55. It's not clear what you think is "wrong" in the computations given there.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux yes it is not working for double values. Required to convert double to string for both parameter i.e String.valueOf(leftOperand); for given BigDecimal solution.

Comment: @Bhumika: is it the part of Expression Evaluator ?. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `BigDecimal`

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("100");
BigDecimal ans = bd.multiple(new BigDecimal("2.55"));
System.out.println(ans);
```

**See Also**

- [Working IDE One demo](http://ideone.com/cnQDb)
- [Retain precision with double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

This is due to [floating point precision problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). It is impossible to represent every rational number within 64 bits. The numbers are stored within the [IEEE 754 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

If you are creating a game, this is more than good enough, even float will do. But if you are doing some finance, it should be correct. Then you can use [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). It is much slower than `double` but it is correct. And it takes much more memory, since you have an exact value in memory. Here is a nice tutorial on how to use [BigDecimal](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal%3a_A_Tutorial).

Answer (score -1):

**Using Math.round().**

```
public static double evaluate(final double leftOperand, final double rightOperand) {
        Double rtnValue = new Double(leftOperand * rightOperand);
        return Math.round(rtnValue.doubleValue());
    }
```