# Loss of precision in java

Tags: java, type-conversion

All integer literals are treated as int in java and floating point literals are treated as double in java.
Then why does

```
    byte b =10;
```

does not give any error but

```
   float f = 10.0;
```

gives a loss of precision error when in both cases down-casting takes place?

Comment: read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: It is because of the standards defined for floating point numbers. Read more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is float in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076710/what-is-float-in-java)

Comment: Note that with an `f` suffix, you get a `float` literal rather than a `double` literal... and with an `L` suffix, you get a `long` literal rather than an `int` literal. So your first sentence is a little overly broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `int` to `byte`, there's no real concern about a loss of *precision*, because both types have the same degree of granularity. You'll get an error if you try to convert a literal with a value outside the *range* of `byte` to `byte`. (The error message given in that case is slightly misleading.)

In the case of `double` to `float`, you can have a constant value which is in the right *range*, but still lose *precision*. In your specific case of 10.0, the value can be represented exactly in both `float` and `double`, but that's not the case in general.

As an example of that, consider this:

```
float f = (float) 10.1; // Or float f = 10.1f;
double d = 10.1;
System.out.println(f == d); // Prints false
```

That's because precision is being lost in the conversion from `double` to`float` - neither type can represent 10.1 exactly, but `double` gets close to it than `float` does. The `==` operator will mean `f` is converted back to a `double`, with a different value to `d`.

Comment: Awesome explanation sir!! I never expected 10.1 (float) equals 10.1 (double) to be false (after type conversion)