# Constructor Overloading Error

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

I cant figure out the errors! But while compiling it shows error. Please help me out.....

```
// This program is used to find the area of a circle and a rectangle    
// through constructor overloading concept.

class area {
    float radius;
    int l , b;
    public area(float r) {
        radius=r;
    }
    public area(int a , int d) {
        l=a;
        b=d;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Area of Circle is = "+(3.14*radius*radius));
        System.out.println("Area of Rectangle is = "+(l*b));
    }
}

class constadd {
    public static void main(String arr[]) {
        area c = new area(4.5);
        c.display();
        area e=new area(4,5);
        e.display();
    }
}`
```

Comment: You should call display() only after all of the 3 instance variables have been initialised. Or, alternatively, write 2 different display() methods for each area, OR initialise the 3 variables with default values.

Comment: Am_I_Helpful is right, in display you are working with all fields.

Comment: I recommend to have two different classes which extends `Area`. Or implements an interface for it. Depending on which constructor was invoked the class will behave differently. That is a sign that your class is in fact several classes.

Comment: What is the question?  If the program doesn't do what you expect, change it.  It appears you have simple not set the variables you use later. so set them.

Comment: have a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076710/what-is-float-in-java

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade I'm not quite sure how C# constructor overloading is relevant to a question about java constructor overloading, especially since the overload isn't the actual problem..

Answer (score 1):

Use double instead of float.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class area {
double radius;
int l , b;
public area(double r) {
    radius=r;
}
public area(int a , int d) {
    l=a;
    b=d;
}
public void display() {
    System.out.println("Area of Circle is = "+(3.14*radius*radius));
    System.out.println("Area of Rectangle is = "+(l*b));
}
}

class  Ideone {
    public static void main(String arr[]) {
    area c = new area(4.5);

    c.display();
     area e=new area(4,5);
    e.display();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Anik mentioned, either change the constructor to take double as a parameter instead of float or while calling this constructor use suffix 4.5 with 'f' to specify that you want to pass float i.e., new area(4.5f);