# why float and double showing different behaviour in java?

Tags: java, types

case 1

```
float a=033.0   //shows compilation problem
```

case 2

```
double a=033.0 //works fine
```

Why case 1 is showing error but not case 2 or vice-versa?

Comment: The issue you are describing is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076710/what-is-float-in-java

Answer (score 0):

By default java uses double type to store floating values. since you are storing double in float (down casting) java will throw an error. it can be resolved by two ways

1. float a=033.0f
2. float a= (float)033.0

Answer (score 0):

case 1----float a=033.0 //shows compilation problem

case 2----double a=033.0 //works fine

In Java,  decimal number is interpreted as a double ,so converting from double to float cannot be performed automatically ,so you need to give like this :
float a= 033.0f;

Answer (score 0):

Its simply the understanding of Java Syntax.
You can read the Primitive data types of java.
You'll get it anywhere...

Link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Direct to this link, do ctrl+F, & paste this "Floating-Point Literals".
You wont't waste time wandering...

For your own convenience now, you can prefer this.

float fractionNumber = 25.24F; 
fractionNumber = 25.24f;

double biggerFractionNum = 56.65555D;

biggerFractionNum = 56.65555;

but generally its like this all over... later you'll get used to it.

float foo = 34.4F;

double doo = 34.4; 
**IMPLEMENT** it right away ! ...experience it, understand it...& you'll never forget it. :)