# Primitive type of 32.0 % 6 in Java

Tags: java, types, type-conversion, primitive

I'm taking an intro to Java class that asks the following question:

Select the primitive type of this expression's result: 32.0 % 6
choices: int, float, double, long

I chose float, but the correct answer is double. I don't understand; 32.0 % 6 = 2.0, which falls within the ranges of both float and double. Why is one right and the other wrong?

The explanation given is "The 6 is promoted from an int to a double, which then leads to a double result."

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076710/what-is-float-in-java

Comment: Because 32.0 is a `double`.  And when you do mathematical operations with a `double`, you end up with a `double`.

Comment: The int promotion isn't very relevant here. Even if you could divide a double by an int, the result would presumably be double.

Comment: @ruakh Cannot see the connection with your alleged duplicate.

Comment: As per the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2): *A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d`*

Comment: @user207421: The connection is that they have the same basic question ("why is this a double instead of a float?") and the same answer ("because floating-point literals are doubles unless they end in `f`").

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a floating point literal that is not terminated by the character "f" is a `double`. That includes the literal `32.0`.

A modulo applied to a `double` will result in a `double`, hence the answer is `double`.

`1.0` is a `double` even though it fits comfortably in a float. If you try something like `float x = 1.0;`, you will get an error that says `incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float`. But if you do `float x = 1.0f;`, everything will be OK.

There are rules for how types are promoted. The rule of thumb is, the result of an expression will be the widest type or an error. In your case, everything becomes a `double`.